# sed not printing matching group as expected

Tags: regex, sed, match

I am searching for a particular pattern in a csv file. I would like to print the value of the second-to-last column if its value matches `[0-9]{5}`.

For example, let's say I have `file.csv` containing only one line of text:

```
col1,col2,col3,12345,col5
```

So I'm trying to print `12345`. Here is the command I tried:

```
sed -nr 's/,([0-9]{5}),[^,]*$/\1/p' file.csv
```

However, this prints `col1,col2,col312345`.

Then, I tried

```
sed -nr 's/.*,([0-9]{5}),[^,]*$/\1/p' file.csv
```

which worked perfectly, printing `12345`.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding `sed` or just regex in general, but when I test the first regex on [www.regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ot8hSm/1), it behaves as I originally expected it to.

Why did prepending a `.*` to the pattern make a difference / fix the problem, and also why did the first pattern print what it did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `s/pattern/replacement/p` takes *a line* that matches *`pattern`*, performs the substitution and then prints *the whole line*.<sup>1</sup> So, you have this line:

```
col1,col2,col3,12345,col5
```

Your pattern `/,([0-9]{5}),[^,]*$/` matches the line, specifically `,12345,col5`. You substitute that with the capture group, `12345`, so the line is now

```
col1,col2,col312345
```

and the `p` flag prints the whole line.

In your second command, the pattern `/.*,([0-9]{5}),[^,]*$/` matches the line as well, but this time, it matches *the whole line*, and you substitute *the whole line* with the capture group.

---

<sup>1</sup> In sed parlance, the line is loaded into the "pattern space", and you're manipulating the pattern space. At the end of each cycle, the pattern space gets printed (or whenever an explicit `p` command is given). I think you assumed that the `p` flag in the `s` command affects only the substituted part, but it's the whole pattern space.